# How to know whether data has been retrieved from the database?

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am passing a query to mysql using php and I want to know how can I check if the mysql returned something?
for example if I want to know if the data is submitted, I use mysql_affected_rows. I want to know if I got some  data from mysql.

Comment: use mysql_num_rows, It will shows the no of affected rows, If greater than 0, Then some rows are affected...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use the [mysql_info()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-info.html) function, it retrieves a string providing information about the most recently executed statement.

Note this works only for functions listed on the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-info.html).

The [UPDATE statement](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html) returns the number of rows that were actually changed. The mysql_info() C API function returns the number of rows that were **matched and updated** and the number of **warnings** that occurred during the UPDATE.

Example output after UPDATE:

```
Rows matched: 40 Changed: 40 Warnings: 0
```

Exmaple output after INSERT:

```
Records: 3 Duplicates: 0 Warnings: 0
```